# How can I correctly translate this python tensorflow code to NodeJS?

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, prediction

I'm trying to convert a piece of code that uses a tensorflow keras model from Python to NodeJS.
I've already converted the model itself to a tfjs model but I'm having some issues with the predictions, would someone be able to tell me what the difference between the two is that causes the NodeJS prediction to be 100% inaccurate?

Python:

```py
                            url = embed.image.url
                            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                                async with session.get(url=url) as resp:
                                    if resp.status == 200:
                                        content = await resp.read()
                                        image_data = BytesIO(content)
                                        image = Image.open(image_data)
                            preprocessed_image = await preprocess_image(image)
                            predictions = loaded_model.predict(preprocessed_image)
                            print(predictions)
                            data_x = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
                            name= list(data.keys())[data_x[0]]
                            print(f'{name}')


async def preprocess_image(image):
    image = image.resize((64, 64))
    image = np.array(image)
    image1 = image / 255.0
    image = np.expand_dims(image1, axis=0)
    return image
```

NodeJS:

```js
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const { Image } = require('image-js'); // You may need to install an image processing library like 'image-js'

async function predict(url, channel) {
  model = await tf.loadLayersModel("file://new/model.json");
  const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });

  if (response.status === 200) {
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data);

    // Convert the image buffer to an Image object (assuming it's a supported format)
    const image = await Image.load(imageBuffer);

    // Preprocess the image
    const preprocessedImage = await preprocessImage(image);

    try {
      // Ensure input data is defined and has the correct shape
      if (preprocessedImage) {
        const predictions = await model.predict(preprocessedImage);
        data = await loadPokemonData()
        const data_x = predictions.argMax(1).dataSync();
        const name = Object.keys(data)[data_x];
        //console.log('Predictions:', predictions);
        const maxIndex = tf.argMax(predictions, 1).dataSync()[0];
        console.log(maxIndex)
        const newName = Object.keys(data)[maxIndex];
        console.log(`The pokemon is: ${name, newName}`)
        channel.send(`The pokemon is: ${name, newName}`)
      } else {
        console.error('Input data is undefined.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }
}

async function preprocessImage(image) {
  const resizedImage = await image.resize({ width: 64, height: 64 });

  const normalizedImage = resizedImage.divide(255);
  saveProcessedImageAsFile(normalizedImage, './processed.png')

  const tensorImage = tf.browser.fromPixels(normalizedImage);
  const expandedImage = tf.expandDims(tensorImage, 0);

  return expandedImage;
}

async function saveProcessedImageAsFile(processedImage, outputPath) {
  const imageBuffer = await processedImage.toBuffer('image/png');

  fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, imageBuffer);
}

function loadPokemonData() {
  try {
    const rawData = fs.readFileSync('./data/pokemon.json');
    const pokemonData = JSON.parse(rawData);
    return pokemonData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading Pokémon data:', error.message);
    return null;
  }
}

predict("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1155407472421519431/1155463265128812614/pokemon.jpg")
```